# EditText OnLongClickListener triggering multiple events

Tags: android

I need to add an OnLongClickListener to an EditText view.

I can get it to work alongside some default events, but I don't want the default events to trigger at all. As default behavior a dialog will appear to select Input Method.

I thought I had found a solution with setting the android:longClickable attribute in the view xml to false, but apparently that did nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure there's enough here for a proper answer, but here's a guess. If you return true, you've consumed the event and any further actions will not be taken. If you return false, you allow the OS to process the default LongClick action.

```
OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //doSomething();
        return true; //true = event consumed, false = event not consumed
    }
};
```